# How to get type of the object name stored in a string variable?

Tags: string, object, powerbuilder

I have an object name in a string variable. I need to find the type of the object. i could use LibraryExport function but i do not know which library has the object.

for example 
    String TheObj = "dw_grid_report"

How do i know either "dw_grid_report" is a window or a datawindow object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindClassDefinition (*classname*) is your friend.

Comment: pretty expensive at performance but at least there is the way. I changed the coding technique.